# How to send request body through GET request to external API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, rest

How to send json data in request body through GET request to external API in Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, ***you can't send a body request using http `GET` verb***.

If you are looking for a way to call external API by sending data in request body, you have the choice between `restTemplate` and `webClient`, prefer the latter if the external API is async.

Examples Using `RestTemplate` :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
BookModel book = new BookModel("effective java");
String bookAsJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(book);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(bookAsJson, headers);
String dataResult = restTemplate.postForObject("http://external-api-here/book", request, String.class);
```

Comment: I am trying using resttemplate.exchange for GET but getting Bad request error is that body is not accepting by other API or can you please look on to this below question I have provided more details.     https://stackoverflow.com/q/64683261/11478835

Answer (score 0):

Please code might help. From "res" get your pojo.

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;


RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            
String url = "<external api url>";
            
JsonObject jsobObject=new JsonObject();
jsobObject.addProperty("someJsonProperty", "someJsonPropertyValue");
HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
headers.add("Content-Type",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
            
HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(jsobObject.toString(), headers);
            
String res = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class).getBody();
```